# MongoDB group by aggregation query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, group-by, pipeline, aggregation

The data I have is:

```js
[
    { type: 'software' },
    { type: 'hardware' },
    { type: 'software' },
    { type: 'network' },
    { type: 'test' },
    ...
]
```

I want to create a MongoDB group by aggregation pipeline to return the data like this:
I only want 3 objects in result
the third object in result {_id: 'other', count: 2}, This should be the sum of counts of type other that software and hardware

```js
[
    {_id: 'software', count: 2},
    {_id: 'hardware', count: 1},
    {_id: 'other', count: 2},
]
```

Comment: Does this data stored in a field of a single document, or those are separate documents?

Comment: @AlexZeDim those are separate documents.

Comment: than you might wanna check and accept my answer by pressing the green mark below its rating (and probably upvote, if my answer is correct)

Comment: I updated my query, you may check the results once more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [the exact query (MongoPlayground)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rxYXC2AVqvP) that you need if those data are separate documents. Just add `$project` stage before group and then [`$switch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) operator. (If those field data are number, you might wanna check [`$bucket`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/index.html)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      type: {
        "$switch": {
          "branches": [
            {
              "case": {
                "$eq": [
                  "$type",
                  "software"
                ]
              },
              "then": "software"
            },
            {
              "case": {
                "$eq": [
                  "$type",
                  "hardware"
                ]
              },
              "then": "hardware"
            }
          ],
          default: "other"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$type",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

> *Also, I'd like to recommend avoiding field name `type`. Actually it doesn't reserve in MongoDB, but however it could bring conflicts with some drivers since, in schema/model files, type fields are referred to the exact BSON type of the field.*

Comment: This wont work because of the third object in result {_id: 'other', count: 2}, This should be the  sum of counts of type other that software and hardware.

Comment: I only want 3 objects in result

Comment: the result am getting for your query is
[
  {
    "_id": "test",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "network",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "software",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "hardware",
    "count": 1
  }
]

Comment: Oh, that, Then update the question with such clarification, and I'll update my answer, and are you absolutely sure, that you'll need aggregation framework, instead of 3 separate request? It's much better to do 3 requests in parallel, instead of using [`$switch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch)

Comment: Don't you think that 3 request will take more time to get the result?
are you suggesting to use $facet (aggregation)?

Comment: @sandy using `$facet` in this case is "too-much" I guess. I was thinking about `.find` in `Promise.all[queries]` but I rethink my own idea and guess, that if your collection is shaded, `countDocumentsEsp` couldn't be an option.